# Optimise Table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, html-table

I have a table with over 7500 lines of data from MySQL-PHP. The app is built on Codeigniter 3. I am ***not*** using DataTables. However, every time the page loads, it takes over 15 seconds to render. I have tried to use Page Caching, but even using the browser Back Button loads the page from scratch.

Controller Methods:

```
public function index() {   
    $data['title'] = 'Patient List';
    $data['patient'] = $this->patient_model->get_patients();

    if(isset($_SESSION['patientChanged'])) { 
        if($_SESSION['patientChanged'] == 1) {
            $this->output->delete_cache();
            $this->output->cache(10);
            $_SESSION['patientChanged'] == NULL;
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('patient_list');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function insert() {
    $result = $this->patient_model->insert_patient();
    $_SESSION['patientChanged'] = 1;
    redirect ('patient/view/'.$result);
}
```

Is there any way to optimise this? Can the page load time be reduced below 5 sec?

Comment: How much lines do you want to display? You could use paging and split those lines into multiple pages. So one page doesn't have to fetch that much lines and loads faster.

Comment: @thmspl How do you do that without DataTables?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to check whether the patient was registered earlier by searching through the entire data. My table displays only the Name & Phone columns to minimise the no. of <td> elements.

Comment: Which patient? Surely if you have some patient data you could limit the query to at least only the `Patels`

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about how to make paging with php. Theres no difference if you use datatables or whatever.

Comment: I was searching for 2 seconds on google and found a codeigniter-pagination class. You need to use google more often specially if you are new with programming!

Comment: rendering a 7500 row table should take that long, as long as the query itself is inneficient. We don't know anything about your table structure or what happens in your `$this->patient_model->get_patients()` model call so it's hard to guess anything. I'd suspect the culprit is the database query/queries you're running in your model, not the on-screen rendering itself

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) in question.  And the `SELECT` you are using for "registered earlier by searching".  That is probably were you need help.

Comment: @thmspl yes, codeigniter pagination class seems to solve the problem. I tried out a basic solution, the results are quite good. Need to match it with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add INDEXES in table & paginate your result with LIMIT & OFFSET.
Pagination to your result will help you to retrieve limited record instead of full list